# Months between 2 dates | postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, monthcalendar

I have 2 dates  `1-Jan-18` , `1-Apr-18`
and I want that by giving start and end date function returns all the month like:

```
jan 18
Feb 18
Mar-18
Apr-18
```

all the month list that lies in between the date.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) but it will fail if your dates are not on the same date - e.g. if the start date is `2017-10-30` and the end date is `2018-02-28`

```sql
SELECT generate_series('2018-01-01','2018-04-01',interval '1 month');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your function using `generate_series` and `interval 1 day` like below:

```sql
create or replace function calculate_month(startdate date , enddate date)
returns table (months text) as
$$
begin
return query
select 
distinct to_char(x,'Mon-YY') 
from  ( 
       select generate_series(startdate,enddate,interval '1 day') as x
       ) q ;

end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

and then call your function like below:

```
select * from calculate_month('2020-01-01', '2020-04-04');
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=dae47f34462b51fb3ba3ca7170fcc74b)